# Knockout.JS print a list of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

How can I get the following knockout.js snippet to print the number as the link text. Or a better way to ask might be what is the anonymous variable named, so i can use it in the loop?

```
<span data-bind="foreach:  ko.utils.range(1, 30)">
    <a hre="#" data-bind="text: ????"></a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `$data` is what you're looking for. The `$data` keyword is new in knockout 2.0.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/181/

Other new "psuedo-variables" new in Knockout 2.0:

- $data – returns the current item
- $parent – returns the item from the parent binding context
- $parents – an array containing all the parent binding contexts. $parents[0] == $parent, then $parents[1](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/12/21/knockout-2-0-0-released/) is the level above that, and so on.
- $root – returns the item at the top level of binding (usually your primary view model)

([Source](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/12/21/knockout-2-0-0-released/))